# Can a revoked degree cause problems for permanent residence?

Tags: civil-law

Suppose a person has been granted permanent residence in Canada. Further suppose residency was granted partly on the basis of the person's academic degree. Now suppose the degree is revoked by the university that issued it. (The university is not in Canada.) Will Canada revoke the person's permanent residence?